# Set input caret position on blur in Safari without refocusing input

Tags: javascript, html, focus, caret, onblur

[⏯ Playground Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mv08ekay/3/) (before the answer)
[⏯ Playground Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mv08ekay/5/) (after the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67071637/112882)

```html
<style>input[type=text] { width: 3em; text-overflow: ellipsis; }</style>
<input id=a type=text value=123456789><br>
<input id=b type=text value=123456789>

<script>
  a.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
    if (event.target.selectionStart > 0)
      event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
  });
</script>
```

`event.target.setSelectionRange(0, 0);` is something

- added to **PDF.js** for **Firefox**

  - to address this issue: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/12359 
    move text cursor to start on blur (works with no JS code in all other browsers)
  - due to an 8-year-old bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=860329

Now,

1. **Firefox** is the only browser that requires `setSelectionRange` for 12359
2. **Safari** is the only browser where `setSelectionRange` interferes with blur (focus loss/change) 
   `setSelectionRange` traps the user into `#a` in **Safari** with no way out!
   `selectionStart > 0` that I have added helps one escape on second attempt.

does anyone see an ultimate fix that satisfies the quirks of *all* browsers including **Safari** and **Firefox**?

---

Following up with **Safari**: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224425

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to use `setSelectionRange(0, 0)` to reset the scroll position. Doesn't `input.scrollLeft = 0;` work?

Comment: Thank you. I will submit a pull request tomorrow. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: @EmilioCobosÁlvarez, I was not the person who used `setSelectionRange(0, 0)` in the first place. It is the most popular result in web searches for input element caret positioning questions though, so I can see why it was used.

Comment: @EmilioCobosÁlvarez - sent pull request - see: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/13232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to setSelectionRange() to update the scroll position. `input.scrollLeft = 0;` would have the same effect without the side effects in Safari.

Comment: Great! Github-mentioned you in https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/13232.

Comment: what if we want the cursr at the end on blur.. how can we avoid the focus trap in safari ?